# How to load current product in Magento 2 without using deprecated functionality?

Tags: magento2, product, best-practice, deprecated

The core uses two deprecated classes to load the current product within the block class on the front end:

- `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`
- `\Magento\Framework\Registry`

See: `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct::getProduct()` and `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView::getProduct()`. One of many classes that uses these deprecated objects is: `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Simple` (declared as `product.info.simple` in layout XML).

I would like to load a product in a [ViewModel](https://www.yireo.com/blog/2017-08-12-viewmodels-in-magento-2) without using deprecated tools. How can I do this?

Comment: Don’t load again. You can use their function, in future Magento update that. If you still want to load then try repository

Comment: @SohelRana, I should update to say "access". The repository would work but the question is *what* product to load (currently solved by using the deprecated registry).

Comment: Check https://github.com/Vinai/module-current-product-example

Answer (score -1):

If you are on product page in Magento 2 then if you want to get current product.
So for that you can get current product id like below :

**In Controller,Block,Phtml ->**

```
$currentProductId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

**In Observer ->**

```
$currentProductId = $observer->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

**Then load current product by current product id.**

*If its not correct then please let me know where you want current product.*

Comment: `$observer->getRequest()->getParam('id')` does not work, since `getRequest()` returns null on observer.